Does Kali Linux OS actually have malware?
I downloaded the Kali Linux 64 bit from TechSpot, and I know that it has a 100% safe download. But I ran it though Windows Security and it found 77 threats. Most of them I know are just part of Linux because there classified as Hack Tool. But there are several Trojan Horses and ransomware. I just want to be sure it's safe to use before I remove Windows and install it as the OS on my second laptop


Your choice of location to download the file strikes me as strange; rather than get from the official site you download from somewhere else that promises its an original file??  How do you know it has "100% safe download" or that is the Kali Linux you wanted?  What checks did you perform to ensure it's not an altered file; given you chose to download from a third party?  I'd firstly have checked the file has being genuine, but you provide no proof that you actually checked anything, but instead appear to be trusting the 3rd party techspot site.

My goal is to wipe window from my second laptop and install Kali Linux I'm doing this by using a USB. I first downloaded it from Kali Linux own website and was using Rufus to put it on a USB when Windows Security pop and said threats found. I stop everything and removed it running a scan and deleting all recently downloaded files. I then remember that this was supposed to happen as Kali Linux has Pen testing tools on it. So, i started again, but I look around and found TechSpot, a website rated safe by top security sites. I downloaded from there and then scanned the file finding the 77 threats

I'm 99% sure that its just windows reading it as a threat, but I'm a cautious person who like to learn and make sure he's not making mistakes. I made sure to fully check out TechSpot before downloading from it. And I made sure it the right version as well. Mine main goal of asking the question was to see if anyone had past encountered this and what their experience is. I put the ios file on a USB using Rufus and plan to install it on my laptop, download a antivirus and scan it to insure there are no malware and that it was just Tools that come with Linux.

Windows does not know anything about Linux ... how can it make decisions about what a Linux virus looks like?

If you trust kali.org and sha256's sum matchs you could install.

Kali Linux is NOT designed for use as desktop Linux distro like you intend. Please read and understand: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5360/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me

Antiviruses have treated pentest/hacking/cracking/password recovery tools as malware for ages.
Kali Linux is full of them.
And to be completely honest, some of those tools may as well be actual pieces of malware because there's no oversight. Some github repos created by God knows whom, not tested by any other distro or AV researchers. Tread carefully.
When I need to use them I actually fire up a virtual machine.
